# How do I get my class function to return a letter instead of a number?

Tags: python, class

Okay, I have implemented my code below. The wanted outcome would be:

```
Card Q Hearts, Card 9 Hearts, Card 7 Spades
```

Instead, the outcome is:

```
Card 12 Hearts, Card 9 Hearts, Card 7 Spades
```

I know that the mistake is somewhere in the `if` statement but I can't figure out how I should fix it. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

```
import random
class Card:
    ranks = range(1, 14)
    suits = ['Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Hearts']

    def __init__(self):
        self.rank = random.choice(Card.ranks)
        self.suit = random.choice(Card.suits)

    def change(self):
        self.rank = random.choice(Card.ranks)
        self.suit = random.choice(Card.suits)

    def __repr__(self):
        letters = {1:'A', 11:'J', 12:'Q', 13:'K'}
        if self.rank in letters:
            rank_show = self.rank
        else:
            rank_show = self.rank
        return "Card " + str(rank_show) + " " + self.suit

random.seed(1235)
card_1 = Card()
print(card_1)
card_2 = Card()
print(card_2)
card_2.change()
print(card_2)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably want `__init__` to be deterministic and take a rank and a suit as an explicit argument. A class method like `def random(cls): return cls(choice(cls.ranks), choice(rank.suits))` would be better for the alternate method of generating a random `Card`.

Comment: Further, you probably don't want to create a random card; rather you want to *select* a random card from a deterministically constructed collection of cards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    letters = {1:'A', 11:'J', 12:'Q', 13:'K'}
    if self.rank in letters:
        rank_show = self.rank
    else:
        rank_show = self.rank
```

You forgot to change the show value: you do the same thing in both branches.  Instead ...

```
    if self.rank in letters:
        rank_show = letters[self.rank]
```

Better yet, make sure that your return value is of a consistent type: just make them all characters:

```
    rank_char = " A23456789TJQK"   # 'T' for 10 is common for consistent formatting
    rank_show = rank_char[self.rank]
```

Note the lack of an 'if' statement; you simply index the value list.  If you want to include "10" instead of "T", you might use a list of strings instead:

```
    rank_char = ["", "A", "2", ... "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a minor mistake. You are accessing the numerical value of self.rank even though you have a dictionary which maps the corresponding alphabet for it. To fix this just use self.rank as key for the dictionary.

```
def __repr__(self):
        letters = {1:'A', 11:'J', 12:'Q', 13:'K'}
        if self.rank in letters:
            rank_show = letters[self.rank] #change here - using self.rank as the key for letters
        else:
            rank_show = self.rank
        return "Card " + str(rank_show) + " " + self.suit
```

Another method of doing it is to use the get() method of the dictionary data type.

```
def __repr__(self):
    letters = {1:'A', 11:'J', 12:'Q', 13:'K'}
    if self.rank in letters:
        rank_show = letters.get(self.rank) #change here - use letters.get
    else:
        rank_show = self.rank
    return "Card " + str(rank_show) + " " + self.suit
```